# Guards in list comprehensions don't terminate infinite lists?

Tags: haskell

I thought this :

```
[i | i <- [1..], i < 5]
```

would produce

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

just like

```
take 4 [i | i <- [1..]]
```

A finite length list.

But it doesn't, it seems to be infinite because any attempt to treat it as a finite list just causes hang (ghci).

I am not sure how to understand this exactly. Is it some kind of infinite generator which simply produces nothing after the fourth item but never stops?

Basically the code keeps generating new items because it doesn't know they can never satisfy the criterion?

Comment: For this particular use, you could write `[1..4]`. (Not an answer to the question, just another way of forming lists that you may not have known about.)

Comment: Even if GHC did realize at compile time that none of the remaining items were going to pass the predicate, it wouldn't behave any differently (it might throw an exception instead of hanging, but it wouldn't give you a terminated list). The value of your expression is `1:2:3:4:⊥`, which is not the same value as `1:2:3:4:[]`. That doesn't mean you *couldn't* use former list; just don't try to look at items past the fourth one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You literally told the program to check every element of the infinite list and include only the ones that are less than 5.  As you say, the compiler doesn’t realize that no remaining element of the list will ever satisfy the condition.  Nor could it, even in theory, create such a proof at runtime if passed an arbitrary list.  It just does what you said, and keeps checking every element.

This is not necessarily a bug if the program does not try to evaluate `xs` in the result `1:2:3:4:xs`, due to lazy evaluation.  Taking the `head` should work just fine.  If you tell it to find the length of the list or something like that, though, it’s an infinite loop.

One way to do what you (probably?) want is [`takeWhile`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:takeWhile), which stops when the condition is no longer true.

Comment: Just for reference [here is the definition of `takeWhile` on Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:takeWhile).